# jQuery - post request with image using ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

How do I send FormData to a controller? I am trying to upload an image:

```
$(".Replybtn").on("click", function() {

  var fileData = new FormData();
  var files = $(".Rfile[data-id=" + RId + "]").get(0).files;

  if (files.length > 0) {
    fileData.append("HelpSectionImages", files[0]);
  }

  $.post('/QJN/Reply/', {
    __RequestVerificationToken: gettoken(),
    TGID: RId,
    SID: UId,
    Com: cmnt
  }, function(data) {
    if (data == "Tagged") {
      // 
    }
  });

});
```

HTML

```
<input type="file" class="Rfile" data-id=@feed.TagId accept = "image/*,video/*">
```

Controller

```
   [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken, ValidateInput(enableValidation: true)]
    public ActionResult Reply(string TGID, string SID, string Com)
    {
     var file = Request.Files["HelpSectionImages"]; 
      if(file!=null){

       }
     }
```

Comment: Could you please post your controller action and any relevant HTML? Here is the [jQuery docs on `.post()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) - does your request follow these guidelines?

Comment: Hi,I have updated question

Comment: Is your post request hitting your controller action? Please let us know if @er-han's answer resolves your issue (and if it does, please accept it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not posting `fileData` object. So you don't get any files from `Request`.

Try this:

```
$(".Replybtn").on("click", function () {
var fileData = new FormData();

var files = $(".Rfile[data-id=" + RId + "]").get(0).files;  

if (files.length > 0) {
    fileData.append("HelpSectionImages", files[0]); 
}

fileData.append("__RequestVerificationToken", gettoken());
fileData.append("TGID", RId);
fileData.append("SID", UId);
fileData.append("Com", cmnt);

$.ajax({
  url: '/QJN/Reply/',
  data: fileData,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,// only jQuery 1.6+
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data){
    if (data == "Tagged") {

    } 
  }
});
}
```